# Scrolling to a Specific Anchor After JS Animation/Sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple function that loads after some questioned are clicked and it works fine, but I would like to scroll the page to the anchor with the `.step_button` class at the end of the questions:

```
<div id="if_one">   
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link2.com">IF QUESTION 1 = Option 1</a>
</div>
<div id="if_two">   
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link1.com">IF QUESTION 1 = Option 2</a>
</div>
<div id="if_three"> 
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link1.com">IF QUESTION 1 = Option 3</a>
</div>
```

I think the part of the javascript that would have to be changed is:

```
function run_loading_4(q1) {
    $('.run_loading_4, .loading').hide();
    $('.li_run_loading_4, li_run_loading_5, .run_loading_5, .show_end').fadeIn();
    $('#' + q1).show();
}
```

But I'm not sure..  I also found a way to include a 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/crq29/) so should be easier to figure out, I added a bunch of `<br />` to the fiddle to make sure that the working solution will scroll to the anchors for `step_button`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function to something like this:

```
function run_loading_4(q1) {
        $('.run_loading_4, .loading').hide();
    $('.li_run_loading_4, li_run_loading_5, .run_loading_5, .show_end').fadeIn();
    $('#' + q1).show();
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+q1).offset().top},
        'slow');
    }
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crq29/2/)